# Cartodb - Error: sql is read-only in NamedMaps

Tags: carto, sql, error

My map is not a named map. Map privacy is set to only people with the link. Why I I getting this error when trying to do queries? Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1):

Named Maps are about privacy of datasets, not the map itself. If any of the datasets you are using on your map is set to "*private*" then your map will be exposed as named. So, in order to be able to use normal `setSQL` or `setCSS` functions all your datasets need to be *public* or *with link* on the privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Jorge says in his answer, you might be interested in creating your own Named Maps with variables so that you're able to map and query your private data. I recommend you to take a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html#named-maps-1) and to this tutorial [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/named_maps.html).